# Не работает Drag'n'Drop из samba-шары

Tags: google-chrome, samba, centos7, nas

Имеется старенький NAS Netgear STORA, на которой лежат документы. Сейчас осуществляется переезд на файловый сервер на основа CentOS7+Samba. Со сторы Drag'n'Drop срабатывает куда угодно - и на локальный компьютер, и напрямую в браузер (почта, облако и т.д.). С файлового сервера Drag'n'Drop не срабатывает в хром - выдается сообщение об ошибке, пишет разрыв соединения. При этом через IE всё прекрасно работает.
Стора: samba 3.0.28-0.el5.8.oe5, конфиг https://pastebin.com/tEKSaikE
Сервер: samba version 4.6.2, конфиг https://pastebin.com/FE3qR5P1

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вы на сетевую шару сервера (samba4) ходите интернет эксплорером и при этом все ок? А через что тогда не ок? Проблема только в драг-унд-дропе или обычное копирование тоже не работает? Конфиг 4-й самбы у вас странный - используете секьюрити юзерс, но ни в одной шаре нет valid user опции...

Comment: Проблема только в Drag'n'Drop-е. На шару хожу через обычный проводник, и если перетаскивать оттуда файл в GoogleDrive, который открыт в IE - то все работает, файл в облако грузится. Если открыть GoogleDrive в хроме и перетащить туда, то файл уже не загружается

Comment: А если в гуглдрайв, открытый в хроме, перетащить файл с рабочего стола (диска С), что будет?

Comment: Всё нормально, всё грузится